# How to adjust the color bar size in geopandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I've created this map using geopandas, but I can't make the color bar have the same size as the figure.

```
ax = covid_death_per_millon_geo.plot(column = 'total_deaths_per_million', legend = True, cmap = 'RdYlGn_r', figsize=(20,15))
ax.set_title('Covid deaths per Million', size = 20)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a26oJ.png

Comment: See this: [https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colorbars on GeoPandas plots are Matplotlib `colorbar` objects, so it's worth [checking those docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html).

Add a `legend_kwds` option and define the `shrink` value to change the colorbar's size (this example will shrink it to 50% of the default):

```
ax = covid_death_per_millon_geo.plot(
    column="total_deaths_per_million",
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={
        "shrink":.5
    },
    cmap="RdYlGn_r",
    figsize=(20, 15)
)
```

Alternatively, change the colorbar's `location` to put it below the map. You may want to change both the location and the size:

```
ax = covid_death_per_millon_geo.plot(
    column="total_deaths_per_million",
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={
        "location":"bottom",
        "shrink":.5
    },
    cmap="RdYlGn_r",
    figsize=(20, 15)
)
```